# Normalise all numeric columns in a dataframe by relevant control group with R and dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a large data set with multiple observations of different conditions:

```
Condition = c('A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D')
Control = c('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B')
Value_1 = 1:4
Value_2 = 2 * 1:4
Value_3 = 3 * 1:4

t = data.frame(Condition, Control, Value_1, Value_2, Value_3)

  Condition Control Value_1 Value_2 Value_3
1         A       A       1       2       3
2         A       A       2       4       6
3         B       A       3       6       9
4         B       A       4       8      12
5         C       B       1       2       3
6         C       B       2       4       6
7         D       B       3       6       9
8         D       B       4       8      12
```

I want to divide each of the value columns by the mean of the values of their specified control group. The desired output is:

```
  Condition Control Value_1 Value_2 Value_3
  <chr>     <chr>     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 A         A         0.667   0.667   0.667
2 A         A         1.33    1.33    1.33 
3 B         A         0.857   0.857   0.857
4 B         A         1.14    1.14    1.14 
5 C         C         0.667   0.667   0.667
6 C         C         1.33    1.33    1.33 
7 D         C         0.857   0.857   0.857
8 D         C         1.14    1.14    1.14
```

If I only had one control group and specified the columns then I would use:

```
t %>% group_by(Control) %>%
   mutate(Value_1 = Value_1/Value_1[Condition == 'A'])
```

However here this will not work for several reasons: I have multiple values for each control group that need to be meaned first. I also have multiple controls, and need to specify that the relevant control for each row is the one specified for that row (not just A in every case). I also want to apply the normalisation to every numerical column. I know that `mutate_if(is.numeric, .fun)` can be used to select numeric columns, but I do not know how it would be possible to write a generic function to perform the normalisation to a control group.

With this small dataset it would be easiest to just split it into each control group, and to specify the mutations by naming each colony manually. However I am looking for a solution that can handle larger datasets with arbitrary numbers of variables and control groups.

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: Just updated with the desired output :-)

Comment: What value is column `Value_1` being divided by and why? (looks like it's being divided by 1, but 1 does not appear to be the mean of any "control" values)

Comment: Hi, i just realised I made a mistake in the desired output. Correcting now

Comment: Corrected now. So to take Value_1 as an example: The average for condition A is 1.5, therefore I want each of the individual values for conditions A and B to be divided by 1.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a table of the means for each condition, then left join that to your data. Now that you have the means and the values in the same table, you just need to `transmute` to do the division.

```
cond_means <- 
  t %>% 
    group_by(Condition) %>% 
    summarise_if(is.numeric, mean)

t %>% 
  left_join(cond_means, by = c(Control = 'Condition')) %>% 
  transmute(Condition, 
            Control,
            Value_1 = Value_1.x/Value_1.y,
            Value_2 = Value_2.x/Value_2.y,
            Value_3 = Value_3.x/Value_3.y)

#   Condition Control   Value_1   Value_2   Value_3
# 1         A       A 0.6666667 0.6666667 0.6666667
# 2         A       A 1.3333333 1.3333333 1.3333333
# 3         B       A 2.0000000 2.0000000 2.0000000
# 4         B       A 2.6666667 2.6666667 2.6666667
# 5         C       B 0.2857143 0.2857143 0.2857143
# 6         C       B 0.5714286 0.5714286 0.5714286
# 7         D       B 0.8571429 0.8571429 0.8571429
# 8         D       B 1.1428571 1.1428571 1.1428571
```

One change I made was to use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` when creating the table, because factors are a pain to work with.

```
t = data.frame(Condition, Control, Value_1, Value_2, Value_3, 
               stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Great, thank you. An elegant solution. Also, I think that the default in R 4.0 is stringsAsFactors = FALSE, which makes things a bit easier :-)

Comment: Yep that's true. Enjoy that luxury those of us working for large corporations which don't allow updating to a recent R version don't have (during working hours at least) :)